# Reading the last line of an empty file on python

Tags: python, file

I have this function on my code that is supposed to read a files last line, and if there is no file create one. My issue is when it creates the files and tries to read the last line it comes up as an error.

```
with open(HIGH_SCORES_FILE_PATH, "w+") as file:
        last_line = file.readlines()[-1]
        if last_line == '\n':
            with open(HIGH_SCORES_FILE_PATH, 'a') as file:
                file.write('Jogo:')
                file.write('\n')
                file.write(str(0))
                file.write('\n')
```

I have tried multiple ways of reading the last line but all of the ones I've tried ends in an error.

Comment: What error do you see? Opening a file w+ truncates the file - there will never be any lines in it and `readlines()[-1]` will always be an index error.

Comment: last_line = file.readlines()[-1]
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range this is the error so should i put r+ instead?

Comment: What is the check for a line with only `"\n"` for? Your description doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: i need to read the file for an high score value so I read the last line. if the last line isnt a value it generates 0, so it reads 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a file in "w+" erases any content in the file. `readlines()` returns an empty list and trying to get value results in an `IndexError`. You can test for a file's existence with `os.path.exists` or `os.path.isfile`, or you could use an exception handler to deal with that case.

Start with `last_line` set to a sentinel value. If the open fails, or if no lines are read, `last_line` will not be updated and you can base file creation on that.

```
last_line = None
try:
    with open(HIGH_SCORES_FILE_PATH) as file:
        for last_line in file:
            pass 
except OSError:
    pass

if last_line is None:
    with open(HIGH_SCORES_FILE_PATH, "w") as file:
        file.write('Jogo:\n0\n')
    last_line = '0\n'
```